# React Redux, How load data into a table after the dispatch is completed?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I want to show the table after dispatch is completed.
I have this code

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const { performedActionList } = useSelector(
    ({ adminPerformance }) => adminPerformance
  );

function onChange(value, dateString) {
    if (value) {
      setShow(true);
    } else {
      setShow(false);
    }
    setSelectedDates(dateString);
    dispatch(
      getAdminPerformance({
        pageNumber,
        reportType,
        dates: dateString,
      })
    );
```

I want to set show true after the dispatch completed.

Comment: The question is quite unclear. You need to set data into the state, then check the state and show the table you want depending on that state. Could you provide more details?

Comment: could be done wether by adding the show var to the store and change in the reducer , or your reducer should return a Promise , and set show value , `reducerPromise.then(()=>{ setShow(true)})`

Comment: I am using the state. Updated code. @SadhilSpring I do not know where to add reducerPromis

Comment: @ArunaDissanayake (Assuming you have an async action) use `loading` in your reducer-state ... and if `loading = false` in your component, then you should `setShow`